# Error on activity import: "'1' is not a valid option for field custom_42". Can I find which field this is referring to through the admin interface?

Tags: custom-fields, import

I am importing custom activities (with some custom fields in them) and getting "'1' is not a valid option for field custom_42."

The problem is that I can't figure out which field it's referring to. "1" is not a value I am trying to import so that's no help. Do I have to go into my back end to find the the interface label for "custom_42" or is that exposed in the admin interface anywhere?

Running 4.6.4 on Drupal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find that you can go to this url and find the field you are looking for
/civicrm/admin/custom/group/field/update?action=update&reset=1&id=

Or, to reverse engineer this, go to any existing custom field and mouse over the view/edit links and you should see the field ID along with the field group ID - i just dropped out the field group id to make the url look a little less intimidating.

Comment: THANK YOU!! That worked. I am new to SE so can't upvote your answer but it is right on.