# Importing checkbox data--error "'1' is not a valid option for field"

Tags: import

I have a custom checkbox field, with a value list associated with it. When I try to import into the field, I get an error "'1' is not a valid option for field." "1" is definitely not the data in my .csv file (and as I am testing imports I pulled the values in there directly from the value list so I know they are valid for the field). The error messages for all of the entries say that "1" is not a valid option (though each entry has different data in the field).

I searched the old Civi forums and didn't see an answer to this there either.

Answer (score 1):

I found this similar to [Error on activity import: "'1' is not a valid option for field custom_42". Can I find which field this is referring to through the admin interface?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4330/error-on-activity-import-1-is-not-a-valid-option-for-field-custom-42-can-i)

Comment: Well, it's similar in that it is part of the same issue. But the first one was about identifying the field that the problem was occurring in so that I could try to solve it. This question is about the actual error. So I think they are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

Check your custom fields label and value and value must be same as in your .csv file. Label could be anything but value must match csv file value(if value in csv file 1, 2,3 then you option value for custom field must be 1,2,3).

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that we had this issue today but it took us several attempts to find the cause. It turns out that if you have a custom field where there isn't an option with the value '1' (in our case, we had several options but they started at 3), this can also cause the same error message.