# Importing Custom Field Checkbox Data

Tags: custom-fields, import

I have setup a custom field with 4 options. In my spreadsheet I've tried various combinations of columns which would allow me to import data and select required options. But nothing is working!

Custom Data - Checkbox Options - Red, Blue, Green, Black

In my CSV file I've tried combinations such as

"Red,Blue"

'Red,Blue'

Red,Blue

Is it possible to import data for check box custom data?

Thanks

Alan

Comment: Is your data in multiple columns or one column?  Do your CSV and Civi fields match?  See http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/8407/105 and http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/4333/105

Comment: Thanks for reply Allen. Got in working.
Red,Blue in 1 column
Multi Value Option turned on
I only had check box labels setup. Once I added the values Red, Blue etc then it worked. Obvious when you see it!!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is to put the text

```
Red,Blue
```

without quotes in a single cell of the CSV that you're trying to import.

You also need to make sure that the field you're importing into allows multiple values to be set, not just a single value.

Comment: I'd like to note that inside the CSV, it will look like `"Red,Blue"`, if you enter it as `Red,Blue` in your spreadsheet. So everyone might want to keep that in mind if they are editing actual CSV files.